# Projectile motion 3d odes

Tags: python, numpy, physics, ode, projectile

I am trying to solve this set of differential equations with `solve_ivp` in Python. Winds are horizontal two dimensional vectors, so I need differential equation solved in y dimension.

[image]

This is the error I get:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 4)
```

Is there any other way of solving it? Here is my code:(just projectile motion in x-z plane, distance as function of angle). For the example of two such initial angles (with which we hit approximately the same point) I am trying to calculate the dispersion of hits in the wind according to the point hit in no wind.
Thanks for any help or pointers

```py
from random import randrange
from statistics import stdev
from turtle import title
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    
m = 30
v0 = 301
g = 9.81
ro = 1.28
A = 0.0026
c = 1
k = 0.5 * c * ro * A
B = k / m
V = v0
c_max = 10
c_windx = 0
c_windy = 0

def dSdt(t, S, B, c_windx, c_windy):
    x, vx, y, vy, z, vz = S
    speed = np.hypot(np.hypot((vx + c_windx),(vy + c_windy)), vz)
    return [vx, -B * speed * (vx + c_windx), vy, -B * speed * (vy + c_windy), vz, -B * speed * vz - g]

def distance(angle, B, c_windx, V=v0, t=600):
    v0x = V * np.cos(np.radians(angle))
    v0y = 0
    v0z = V * np.sin(np.radians(angle))
    sol = solve_ivp(dSdt, [0, t], y0 =[0,v0x,0,v0y,0,v0z], t_eval=np.linspace(0,t,10000), args=(B, c_windx,c_windy), atol=1e-7, rtol=1e-4)
    justabove = np.where(np.diff(np.sign(sol.y[2])) < 0)[0][0]
    justunder = justabove + 1
    xloc = (sol.y[0][justabove] + sol.y[0][justunder])/2 
    return xloc

angles = np.linspace(0, 90, 200)
xlocs = np.vectorize(distance)(angles, B=B, c_windx = c_windx)


plt.plot(angles, xlocs)
plt.xlabel('angles []')
plt.ylabel('distance [m]') 
plt.axvline(angles[np.argmax(xlocs)], ls='--', color='r')
plt.text(angles[np.argmax(xlocs)] + 0.2 ,0, round(angles[np.argmax(xlocs)], 2), rotation=90, color='r') 
plt.title('Distance(angle)')
plt.show()

alfa = 15 #its optional

def same_distance_alfa(B,c_windx, V=v0, t=600):
        for a in np.arange(alfa + 5, 90, 0.1):            
            if abs(distance(alfa, B, c_windx, V=v0, t=600) - distance(a, B, c_windx, V=v0, t=600) < 10):
                print((distance(15, B, c_windx, V=v0, t=600) - distance(a, B, c_windx, V=v0, t=600)))
                return a


beta = same_distance_alfa(B)
```

Comment: Your system is six dimensional, but you only pass four initial conditions to `solve_ivp` with `y0 =[0,v0x,0,v0z]`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thanks. so I fixed my code but there are still some errors and it doesnt work. Is anything else I did wrong?

Comment: Your resistance terms in the formulas are wrong. For the velocity `v=v_p+v_w`, the vector resistance is constants times `norm(v)*v`, not just the squares of the separate components. The code has this correctly.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to catch the event(s?) where `y` crosses the zero value in downward direction? The event mechanism of `solve_ivp` can find such points with higher precision than just one step of the bisection method.

Comment: @LutzLehmann no I want to catch event when `z` crosses the zero value, but also know how did the `x` and `y` change so I know where the projectile lands

Comment: The `z` coordinate in your ordering of the components `x,vx,y,vy,z,vz` is `sol.y[4]`. With a defined event, the state at the event roots is recorded in `sol.y_events[0]`. From there you can extract the relevant x and y values. If the event is terminal, the state is also the last in `sol.y`.